# Чому "РПК", а не "РКК"?

Tags: скорочення

Доброго дня!
Питання стосується скорочення назви зброї "ручний кулемет Калашникова" і те чому його скорочення записується як РПК (ручной пулемёт Калашникова) а не РКК (скорочення РПК ми можемо бачити як і у Бойовому статуті сухопутних військ ЗСУ так і на відповідній сторінці Вікіпедії)? Адже в Академічному словнику немає такого слова як "пулемет", а лише є "кулемет".

Comment: Думаю що причина тут лежить не у лінгвістичній площині, а у військово-організаційній.

Comment: А хіба РПК - це не _ручний пістолет-кулемет_ (як загальний вид зброї)?

Comment: бо РПК це позначення моделі конкретної зброї, хоч і походить від скорочення його повної назви. Скажімо WD-40 хоч і походить від  Water Displacement 40, але в Україні продається як WD-40, а не ВВ-40. З РПК та сама історія, це назва моделі іноземного товару і незалежно від її передісторії і значення в іншій мові, має залишатися такою.

Comment: @Miroshko, а можна лінк на конкретну зброю?

Comment: @Miroshko, ваш коментар виглядає як основа для гарної відповіді, якщо її підкріпити джерелами — тобто, посиланнями на якісь промислові стандарти, які в дійсності використовують оригінальну термінологію для назв моделей. Достатньо взяти будь-яку галузь, не обовʼязково військову. Напевно, таких посилань можна знайти досить багато.